# Do I need to go through AppExchange security view to release an App that authenticates with OAuth?

Tags: appexchange, app, connected-apps

I've built a custom application for my company that implements click-to-call functionality within Salesforce. It's been very useful for our inside sales team.

It has two components:

- A browser plugin to add small visual elements to the Salesforce Leads page, and launch a pop-up for notes
- An external webservice that handles the call & writes data into Salesforce via the API.

I want to release this to other organisations, using OAuth 2.0 to get an access token for each additional org.

To use OAuth 2 process and write data into the API for other organisations, do I need to go through the whole AppExchange approval process? *I don't want to list on the AppExchange* - I'm planning to distribute it through my own website.

I'm particularly concerned about avoiding the 3-5 week approval process and $2700 fee.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to list the app on the AppExchange, there is no need for you to go through the security review process. You will miss out on benefits such as being listed on the official AppExchange, and also salesforce.com's license management support, but you don't need those features then skipping the security review is very reasonable.

Comment: One crucial thing you will miss is the Push-Major-Upgrade feature. Incredible but you'll get it only after the review.

Comment: Also, not going through SR means you miss out on whitelisting (connected apps ability to connect to PE/GE orgs).